# For the Lagrangian stationary action formula does the eta function for a specific path vary the distance from the true path?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

This question can apply to any variation calculus problem although it has come up in my case for the stationary action principle so I will stick to the application I am using it for.

The action is denoted by S which is equal to the integral of the Lagrangian. Using the calculus of variations to find the function that minimizes the integral a new function is introduced named Eta.

Each eta represents a new path from the original path. But for each individual eta I *have been assuming* the input values to the eta function vary so that the distance from the true path need not all be equidistant.

In other words it may cross the actual path but not necessarily, it could also just lie a small amount of distance *just above or just below the actual path.*

This is an important distinction but I am not sure if this is a physics question or a math question for someone who is a student of variational calculus. Sorry about that it may be addressed to the wrong audience.

Comment: Can you define what $\eta$ is? Maybe include some explicit equations and notation so that everyone is on the same page.

Comment: There only exists one Eta in mathematics associated with principle of stationary action.  The definition is always the same.   But no matter , I will see if I can use the graphics to include the necessary equations and add them to the question.   I'm just learning the graphics tool on this site so it will take some time.

Comment: You can't ever assume everyone is using the same notation as you. I have a pretty good idea of what you are talking about in your question, but the goal here is to make your questions and the answers to those questions as accessible to everyone as possible. Therefore, you should make sure there is no ambiguity in what you mean by saying "eta", or really anything else.